# Does wrapping all sql calls in ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE remove all concurrency issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

In order to prevent concurrency errors, I've decided to wrap all my sql calls' (which are all in stored procedures) sql statements (all crud operations, such as update / insert/ upserts and even just table reading) with this

> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
> begin tran
>
> > ```
> > --sqlstatements here
> > ```
>
> OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
>
> COMMIT TRAN

let's just say that I am not concerned about performance. I only want to prevent constraint violations, and deadlocks caused by 2 or more simultaneous threads accessing the same database.

Does this effectively remove all deadlocks and also constraint issues arising from race conditions?

Do I still need to explicitly use with (hold lock, update lock) for CUD functions if I already wrap the calls in a serializable transaction?

Comment: You can still have deadlocks, assuming that there's more than one object in the database.

Comment: Try [this](http://nexussharp.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/deadlock-heaven-serializable-isolationlevel/) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by a "concurrency issue". If you include deadlocks in this, then you may still need to include locking hints (eg: `updlock`) in your query

Comment: There is no guarantee that UPDLOCK will prevent all deadlocks

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić No. But the question was "will serializable prevent concurrency issues", and the answer to that is "No"

Comment: Feel free to write that in your answer.